# Merging Two IQueryable results returning error

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have 4 queries using EntityFramework that are running on trailer/truck/car/plant that I need to join together before executing due to the volume of results.

All 4 entities inherit from type Asset.

Here is the code I am trying to execute and different variations of code:

```
 var truckModels = await truckService.GetAll();
 var trailerModels = await trailerService.GetAll();
 var companyCarModels = await companyCarService.GetAll();
 var plantModels = await plantService.GetAll();
```

Without anything:

```
 assetModels = truckModels.Cast<Asset>()
 .Union(trailerModels)
 .Union(companyCarModels)
 .Union(plantModels);
```

With Cast:

```
 assetModels = truckModels.Cast<Asset>()
 .Union(trailerModels.Cast<Asset>())
 .Union(companyCarModels.Cast<Asset>())
 .Union(plantModels.Cast<Asset>());
```

With AsEnumerable:

```
 assetModels = truckModels.Cast<Asset>()
 .Union(trailerModels.AsEnumerable())
 .Union(companyCarModels.AsEnumerable())
 .Union(plantModels.AsEnumerable());
```

With Cast and AsEnumerable:

```
 assetModels = truckModels.Cast<Asset>()
 .Union(trailerModels.Cast<Asset>().AsEnumerable())
 .Union(companyCarModels.Cast<Asset>().AsEnumerable())
 .Union(plantModels.Cast<Asset>().AsEnumerable());
```

However I am getting the following error on all variations:

> "This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."
>
> ```
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.MergeAs(MergeOption mergeOption)
> at lambda_method(Closure )
> at System.Linq.EnumerableExecutor`1.Execute()
> at System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
> at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.Count(IQueryable source)
> at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.CreateDataSourceResult[TModel,TResult](IQueryable queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState, Func`2 selector)
> at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10.<ToDataSourceResultAsync>b__f()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at Viper.Web.Areas.Assets.Controllers.AllController.<GetAssets>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Repositories\ViperRepo\Viper\Viper.Web\Areas\Assets\Controllers\AllController.cs:line 90
> ```

Any ideas? I thought that you could merge IQueryable...

Comment: Not really sure what is going on here, but if all of your queryables are of the same type, can't the query all be done in one go rather than merging 4 together?

Comment: If you do `AsEnumerable()` why would yo get a LINQ to Entities exception... Where exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: Entities are of different type, but all inherit from Asset.
I get the exception when trying to evaluate assetModels

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Edited stack trace above

Comment: Perhaps the `asEnumerable()` calls are forcing the three Union()'ed subqueries to execute before they are unioned, and then they are trying to merge with the `truckModels` queryable, which is still an unmaterialized IQueryable

Comment: I get the same error even when removing the AsEnumerable() calls

Comment: I would think you'd need to cast all of them to `Asset` like you do with `truckModels`. Wild guess though.

Comment: I have just tried that, no change. I have added the code variations above in main post.

Comment: The casting is a red herring. The issue is that you have User Code .net in your Expression Tree.

Comment: @andyb952 `IQueryable` represents a *query*, not the query's results. `Union` will create a UNION query, not merge results. `AsEnumerable()` *executes* each query and returns the results. After that `Enumerable.Union` tries to merge the results. That doesn't really matter though. What does `GetAll` do in the first place? What queries did it create? Why do you talk about `the volume of results`? Do you really need to load *all* object instances from the database? How much data is there?

Comment: @andyb952 besides, unless there's an inheritance relation between the entities, you *can't* create a single query that loads all of them. EF generates SQL statements, it can't do stuff that's impossible to do in SQL. `UNION` and `UNION ALL` require that *all* queries return the same number and type of columns.

Comment: @andyb952 and finally, a UNION wont' make the queries run faster. A UNION returns distinct results which means it has to sort and group the data to remove duplicates. `UNION ALL` is preferable when you know there won't be any duplicates. Individually loading different entities could be faster than using a Union

Answer (score 1):

What is `.GetAll()`. It looks to me that you have an unexpected Closure that can't be converted into an EntityFramework operation.

EntityFramework does not know what `TruckService` nor `TrailerService` is.

If you decompose your Linq Expression, you will find you have an element like

```
Expression.Lambda(
       methodinfo(TruckService.GetAll)
       Expression.Parameter(typeof(TruckService))
)
```

Entity Framework doesn't know that it should reduce that into

```
Expression.Lambda(
       Expression.Call(
            methodInfo(DbContext.DbSet<Truck>),
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(AssetDbContext))
       )
)
```

You have a few options here.

1. Work with an instance of the DbContext directly
2. Construct an ExpressionVisitor to rewrite the Expression tree to make the above transform

However it isn't obvious that the DbContext in each AssetService is the same DbContext, which is required for it to partake in the same query.